# Javascript Onclick pass Object through function in append

Tags: javascript

I'm sorry, I still fresh with Javascript. May I know how to pass the `Object` variable through onClick into the function ?

The code below is my Object:

```
var myObject = {
    id : id,
    email : email,
    name : name,
    type : type
};
```

The code below I use to append:

```
$('#main-container').append(
    '<div>'+
    '<button onclick="passObject('+myObject+')">Submit</button>'+ //how to pass myObject here, I know I pass wrongly ps
    '</div>');
```

The myObject value in function is String type, Besides that, when I get value from object:

```
function passObject(myObject){
    console.log(myObject); // [object Object]
    console.log(myObject.email); //undefined
}
```

Comment: If myObject is in global scope, try just onclick="passObject(myObject)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Attach the event listener properly using Javascript instead, so that `myObject` is visible through the closure, rather than using an inline handler (inline handlers are are hard to manage and are generally considered to be pretty poor practice):

```js
function passObject(myObject){
  console.log(myObject); // [object Object]
  console.log(myObject.email); //undefined
}

const myObject = {
  id : 'id',
  email : 'email',
  name : 'name',
  type : 'type'
};

const div = $(`
  <div>
  <button>Submit</button>
  </div>
`);
div.find('button').on('click', () => passObject(myObject));
$('#main-container').append(div);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main-container"></div>
```

Although in the code above, `myObject` contains strings instead of references to previous values, note that for your code, in ES6+ environments, you can use shorthand property names if you want:

```
const myObject = { id, email, name, type };
```

Comment: Thanks you, I so grateful that was helped me, and save my time.

Answer (score 0):

big re-organise

```
(function() {
    var myObject = {
        id : id,
        email : email,
        name : name,
        type : type
    };

    var btn = $('<button>Submit</button>');

    btn.on( 'click', function( e) {
        e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault();

        console.log(myObject); // [object Object]
        console.log(myObject.email); //undefined

    });

    $('<div/>').append( btn).appendTo('#main-container');

})();
```